# Three.js matrix to rotate and move forward

Tags: three.js

i try to make a rotation and a go forward with matrix but i don't have find solution.

I have try something like this :

```
var finalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var translationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

rotationMatrix.makeRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Vector3(0,addedAngle,0),"XYZ");
translationMatrix.makeTranslation(0,0,step);

finalMatrix.multiply(rotationMatrix);
finalMatrix.multiply(translationMatrix);

myMesh.applyMatrix(finalMatrix);
```

The result is a mesh rotate around origin with a variable radius.
But i want a mesh turn and go forward.

Thx for help.

Comment: Look at `Object3D.translateZ( distance )` and `Object3D.rotateY( angle )`. Read the source code if the documentation is not complete.

Comment: yes i'm working with lookat and translate actually, but i dont anderstand why matrix multiplicate don't give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do a simple matrices multiply to get yoor purpose.
use the code here. To manually set the object matrix, make sure you have set object.matrixAutoUpdate to false.

```
var finalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

rotationMatrix.makeRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Vector3(0,addedAngle,0),"XYZ");

finalMatrix.multiply(rotationMatrix);
finalMatrix.setPosition(0,0,step);

myMesh.applyMatrix(finalMatrix);
```

your can refer to the three.js source code for matrix4.setPosition to make sure the transform operation.
here the setPosiiotn source code:

```
setPosition: function ( v ) {

    var te = this.elements;

    te[ 12 ] = v.x;
    te[ 13 ] = v.y;
    te[ 14 ] = v.z;

    return this;

}
```

Comment: Do not set `matrixAutoUpdate = false` unless you are familiar with the inner-workings of the library and understand the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @WestLangley sometimes I found do rotation, scale,and transform is more easy with the matrix. just         rM = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(rV.y), new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(rV.x));
        rM.premultiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(rV.z));stlMesh.matrix.copy(rM).scale(sV).setPosition(tV);

Comment: three.js was not designed to be used that way. Instead, set the `position`, `quaternion/rotation`, or `scale` properties directly, or use one of the available `Object3D` methods.